# Service Fabric RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) does not get cancelled

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I figured the `RunAsync` method takes a `CancellationToken` as an argument which is great. *Unfortunately to my observations I never gets cancelled.*

Of course cancelling the *RunAsync* method *and* calling *OnCloseAsync* would be kind of redundant. **Still I wonder when (if) the cancellation actually happens.**

Am I supposed to write some additional code to provide a working Stop() method in my client? I would have prefered the cancellationToken in RunAsync would actually be cancelled ;-)

My Service Fabric **Service** code:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is the main entry point for your service instance.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="cancellationToken">Canceled when Service Fabric needs to shut down this service instance.</param>
protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // TODO: Replace the following sample code with your own logic 
    //       or remove this RunAsync override if it's not needed in your service.

    long iterations = 0;

    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // I commented this out because I want my client to handle the cancellation 
        // event gracefully without throwing an OperationCanceled exception.
        //cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        // I never found these messages in any logs. Nor in the diagnostics events window in Visual Studio.
        ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this, "Working-{0}", ++iterations);

        await _client.Start(cancellationToken);

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

My sample **client** implementation:

```
public class Client
{
    private static readonly Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public async Task Start(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.Info("Saying hello from Main Operation.");
            await Task.Delay(3000, cancellationToken);
        }

        _logger.Info("Cancellation requested. Shutting down MainOperation().");
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _logger.Info("Stop requested. But I have no means to stop. Not implemented.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Again, one way to do this, would be to programmatically delete the service when you're done with it, using DeleteServiceAsync You can recreate it too, using CreateServiceAsync.

Comment: Sure. But I don't want to run any code outside of Service Fabric. Also OnCloseAsync is being called, this is fine. I can work with that. Still I wonder when the cancellationToken of RunAsync is ever being set to "cancel".

Comment: You can call it from another service. And it's called when a service stops, to be upgraded, moved from secondary to primary replica and/or for repositioning in the cluster.

Comment: How do you call this cancel from another service?  Can someone please help on understanding the usage of cancellationtoken in that scenario?

Comment: I didn't try it myself, but you can use for example the [Service Fabric Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient.servicemanagementclient.deleteserviceasync?view=azure-dotnet) or [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/Remove-ServiceFabricService?view=azureservicefabricps). If you would ignore the cancellation token in you RunAsync, then the service fabric service cannot shut down gracefully

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the cancellation token is actually cancelled. It is guaranteed. I can assure you, after years of testing and production use, this is not an oversight.

However there is an oversight in your code.

If you're expecting to see this trace output from your client:

```
 _logger.Info("Cancellation requested. Shutting down MainOperation().");
```

You won't, rather it is *extremely* unlikely you'll ever see it. Why? Because this line before it:

```
await Task.Delay(3000, cancellationToken);
```

will **throw OperationCanceledException** when the cancellation token is signaled during the delay. That will kick you out of the loop and out of RunAsync, so your logging line will not execute.

Since you spend 3 seconds in that delay, and nanoseconds outside of it in the loop, you can see why it is extremely unlikely that cancellation would happen when you're not inside the delay.

Comment: If service fabric contains `RunAsync` with a CancellationToken why is there a `CloseAsync`? You know when the service is shutting down by the CancellationToken in `RunAsync` right?

Comment: If a stateless service will shut down, then CloseAsync() will be called on each listener. In parallel, the cancellation token is passed to RunAsync(). If both are finished, then the OnCloseAsync() method the stateless service is called to stop background processes and so on.
You can also implement it into the RunAsync, but sometimes you have to make sure, that all listeners are closed or sometimes it is just cleaner/more readable.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-lifecycle